# Is there any Rails 3 asset pipeline tool that list all assets in use?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

For example: I want to see what images are actually referenced throughout the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at : http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2012/08/23/removing-deadweight-cleaning-up-our-rails-app. The basic idea is to scan your log files for access entries.